# Calling method java select folder

Tags: java, methods, call

I hope you dont mind me asking this as a follow on question..

I'm using

```
ClassMain cm = new ClassMain();
cm.PromptForFolder();
```

from one method to call the method...

```
public String PromptForFolder(Component parent){

  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
  fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

  if(fc.showOpenDialog(parent) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    return fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
  }
  return null;
}
```

I get the error....

`PromptForFolder(java.awt.Component) in ClassMain cannot be applied to ()`

Any body any idea why?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a Component object to the function you are calling.

Look at the signature and match it. You can also pass null.